# python and mysql inserting values in table

Tags: python, mysql

```
class AddTool:
    #def __init__(self):
        #super(AddTool,self).getUsername_password()

    def add(self):
        name=input('\nenter tool name: ')
        compatibility=input('enter the compatibility: ')
        per_day=input('enter rate per day: ')
        per_half_day=input('enter rate per half day: ')
        availability=input('how many available: ')
        try:
            database=mysql.connector.connect(
                    host='localhost',
                    user='root',
                    password='jubeen123',
                    database='Jubeen'
                    )
            cursor=database.cursor()
            command=cursor.execute('insert into Tool (Name,Compatibility,Rate_Per_Day,Rate_Per_Half_Day,Availability) values ("%s","%s",%d,%d,%d)',(name,compatibility,int(per_day),int(per_half_day),int(availability)))
            results=cursor.fetchall()
            for i in results:
                print(i)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I'm getting error

```
Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `?` instead of `%s` and `%d`. OR simply use only `%s` instead of `%d` - even if you use integer values.

Answer (score 0):

As I know in all modules for all databases you use only `%s` (eventually `?`) to show places for values - even it you use integers, floats or other objects.

So you have to use `%s` instead of `%d`

---

**BTW:** Documentation for [MySQL and Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) shows only `%s` or `%(name)s`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Python2 or Python3?

Python3 offers you string formation using variable name in the string itself

Google "Python 3 fstring", it looks something like

```
email = "abc@edf.com"
print(f"This is my email {email}")
```

On python 2 you may use {} and str.format for this operation

```
command=cursor.execute('insert into Tool (Name,Compatibility,Rate_Per_Day,Rate_Per_Half_Day,Availability) values ("{}","{}",{},{},{})'.format(name,compatibility,int(per_day),int(per_half_day),int(availability)))
```

I'm familiar with the percent '%' way but I think sending a formatted query to the execute() method is cleaner than letting it do it